# How to read xml format data and how to get attributes in java

Tags: java

In my table i'm maintains one **xml** column in that column data in **xml** format,so now i got this column with query.

Now how to read xml format data.

here my code:

```
public Object readingSqlResultedRecord(ResultSet result)
{

    try {

        String xml = result.getString(1);
        System.out.println("----xml----"+xml);
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

S.o.p printing **xml** data,in that data contains one property tag,that tag contains **id** and **name** and **title**.
Now how to get **title** attribute.

Comment: you bneed to parse an xml string.use dom parser into order to parse xml and get the attribute that you want using Xpath class in dom parser.

Comment: This question shows no research effort. A Google search would have easily told you the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse XML using java DOM as follow;

```
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(yourXmlfromTable));
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("header");;

       for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node node = nList.item(temp);
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element element = (Element) node;
             String id= element.getAttribute("id");
             System.out.println(id);
             String name =  element.getAttribute("name");
             System.out.println(name);
             String title =  element.getAttribute("title");
             System.out.println(title);
         }
    }
```

Comment: my xml data **<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message body="aGk=" body-html="aGk="><header id="67uud32n-7a8e-4704-91d0-45cf42bn" name="testing" title="Tesing"/></message>** here i want to get title only

Comment: @Sri i have updated my answer.

Comment: Yess it's working fine.Thank's a lot you saves my time and my life

Comment: I'm facing one more problem here that is I have one more **xml** data in that data **id**,**name**,**title** are in Base64 format.so now how to display in string format as same as above **title** attribute.

Comment: Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArray)

Comment: :my  base64 xml data **<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<event access="site" id="24f2cb3d-8a26-448d-d3b-d599feba72e5" range="201603201800000]20160320200000000">
<properties>
<property enc="BASE64" name="CHEF:creator" value="YWRtaW4="/>
<property enc="BASE64" name="CHEF:description" value="bm1ibm1uYm0="/>
<property enc="BASE64" name="DAV:displayname" value="Tm90aWZpY2F0aW4ffd49uIFRlc3RpbmcgaW4gY2FsZW5kYXI="/></properties></event>** i want last property value,how to read it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string as xml. This has been asked before in stackoverflow:

[How to parse a String containing XML in Java and retrieve the value of the root node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408504/how-to-parse-a-string-containing-xml-in-java-and-retrieve-the-value-of-the-root)

[java convert string to xml and parse node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661047/java-convert-string-to-xml-and-parse-node)